# Setting metrics in ubuntu for eth0 and wlan2

Tags: linux, networking, scripting, wifi

I have two scripts, one copying files from machines on closed network (no internet) to the hard drive of the laptop and the other script trying send these files to over the internet using the wlan.

eth0 fixed IP address
wlan2 dhcp address

I understand that I need to set the metrics on these devices to help with this but I'm struggling with setting these. Is they a easy way of setting this as in edit connections the only thing I can see is to set a route to change the metric?

Or is they another way to tell the script just to used the wlan2 connection?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the script(what is it using to copy the data)?  Why won't just general routing wont take care of this?

Answer (score 1):

By my point of view, you can write one script on your laptop that ssh to the machine and copy that files to the certain Dir (on your laptop) , then send it over the internet.